# Prove that $e^{2x} = 3x$ has no solution

Tags: calculus

How can I prove that the equation:

$ e^{2x} = 3x $

has no solution?

I thought to use Rolle's theorem, but I didn't managed to do so,
could you help?

Comment: Hint:  let $f(x)=e^{2x}-3x$.  Can you show that $f(x)$ is always $>0$?

Comment: What made you think of Rolle's theorem? How does the conclusion of Rolle's theorem relate to what you want to prove here?

Answer (score 2):

When $x>0$ (why worry about when $x\le0$?) then
$$e^{2x}>1+2x+2x^2$$
and
$$e^{2x}-4x>1-2x+2x^2=(1-x)^2+x^2.$$
You only wanted $e^{2x}>3x$?

Answer (score 2):

$f(x)=e^{2x}$ is clearly a convex function, and the slope of the tangent line to the graph of $f$ equals $3$ iff $x=\frac{1}{2}\log\frac{3}{2}$. By Jensen's inequality it follows that

$$ \forall x\in\mathbb{R},\qquad f(x)=\color{red}{e^{2x}} \geq 3\left(x-\tfrac{1}{2}\log\tfrac{3}{2}\right)+\tfrac{3}{2}\color{red}{\geq 3x+\tfrac{8}{9}} $$
and $f(x)=3x$ is clearly impossible.

---

Alternative formulation: $g(x)=e^{2x}-3x$ is trivially convex (it is enough to compute $g''$). The only root of $g'$ is at $x=\tfrac{1}{2}\log\tfrac{3}{2}$, where $g(x)>0$. It follows that $g(x)>0$ for any $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I wish I could understand some of your solutions :D

Comment: @Botond: the idea is pretty simple: the graph of the exponential function lies *above* a lot of lines. Above a line with slope $3$, too.

Comment: I'm talking in general. Every time I see one of your answers, I'm like "It looks so elegant, but I can't understand it." Especially when I see your sums. I'll need to take a lot of analysis classes to understand it :D

Answer (score 0):

All of the roots must be positive, because for $x<0$ the RHS is negative, but the LHS is always positive (and $x=0$ is not a root, of course). So from now on, let's assume that $x>0$.

Let
$$e_n(x):= \sum_{i=0}^{n} \frac{x^i}{i!}$$
It's easy to see that
$$e_{n+1}-e_{n} = \frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!} \geqslant 0$$
So $(e_n(x))_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is an increasing sequence. And because
$$e^x=\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \frac{x^n}{n!}=\lim_{n} e_n(x)$$
We have that
$$e^{2x} \geqslant e_{2}(2x)=1+2x+2x^2$$
$$e^{2x} -3x \geqslant 1 -x + 2x^2$$
But the $1-x+2x^2$ is always positive, which implies that:
$$e^{2x}-3x>0$$
So $e^{2x}=3x$ has no real root.

Comment: How to deduce that $e^{2x}\geqslant1+2x+2x^2$ for every $x\geqslant0$ from the fact that $e^{2x}=1+2x+2x^2+\frac{4}{3}x^3+\text{O}(x^4)$ (presumably in the limit $x\to0$)?

Comment: @Did It's not that different, or at least I think I wanted to say something similar. But it's almost a year old answer, and honestly, I was not using the Big-O correctly back then. I will rework it, and ping you when it's ready.

Comment: @Did Is it better now?

Comment: Yes, the proof works now.

Comment: @Did Thank you, and sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Let $$f(x)=e^{2x}-3x$$ Then $$f'(x)=2e^{2x}-3=0$$ for stationary points. So $$e^{2x}=\frac32\implies 2x=\ln\frac32\implies x=\frac12\ln\frac32=\ln\sqrt{\frac32}$$ Since $$f''(x)=4e^{2x}$$ at this $x$, the second derivative is $$4\cdot \frac32=6>0$$ so it is a minimum. There are no other stationary points.

Now notice that at this $x$, $f$ is equal to $\frac32-3\ln\sqrt{\frac32}>0$, meaning that $f$ is always above the $x$-axis.

Thus $e^{2x}=3x$ has no solutions.

Answer (score -1):

Rewriting $e^{2x} = 3x$ as
$$-2x e^{-2x} = -\frac{2}{3}, \tag1$$
we see (1) is exactly in the form for the defining equation for the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function), $\text{W} (x)$. On solving for $x$ in terms of this function we have
$$-2x = \text{W}_\nu \left (-\frac{2}{3} \right ),$$
or
$$x = -\frac{1}{2} \text{W}_\nu \left (-\frac{2}{3} \right ).$$
Here $\nu$ denotes the branches for the Lambert W function. If $\text{W} (x)$ is to be real we require its argument to be greater than or equal to $-1/e$ (in which case the branches $\nu = -1,0$ will be selected when $-1/e \leqslant x < 0$ and $\nu = 0$ when $x \geqslant 0$). As $-2/3 < -1/e$ we conclude the equation are no real solutions.

Comment: How to **avoid** to provide any understanding of the situation, pushing everything under the rug of "the function W has this or that property"...